# PTT mutes mic w/ A20, Delta Zulu, works with older headsets

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, piper-pa-28, headset

New airplane to me. Coms work great using an older headset, David Clark or other brand.  When using my Delta Zulu or Bose A20 the intercoms works fine until you press the PTT.  When pressed the radio keys up but the mic is dead, no sidetone, no audio transmitted from the radio. Thoughts on what could cause this issue only with the newer headsets?  Thanks for any help

Comment: A similar problem with the Bose A20:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64522/instructor-cant-talk-when-h10-13-4-is-plugged-in/64633#64633

Comment: The head set works fine with the intercom, good sidetone and I can talk to other passengers. The problem is only when I key up the radio that the problem occurs.  This is with the pilot side using a yoke mounted inline PTT or the passenger size using the dash mounted PTT.  It’s like the PTT ground connection mutes the mic?